# To what extent is $\textbf{Fld}$ not a filtered category?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory

EDIT: Basically, I want to see if one can construct examples of fields $F,K$ such that they don't have a common extension field.

Apologies in advance if this is obvious, but for example, is there a field containing isomorphic copies of both $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for any prime $p$? If not, what's a good field invariant that could tackle a lot of these kinds of questions? I was thinking of using Galois groups somehow, but not sure where to begin.

This comes from the observation that the underlying set of the geometric realisation (as a locally ringed space) $|F|$ of a functor $F: \textbf{CRing} \to \textbf{Set}$ can be given by $\text{colim}_\textbf{Fld} F(k)$ (limit taken over the functor sending a field $k$ to $F(k)$ and sending $f: k \to K$ to $F(f): F(k) \to F(K)$), where $\textbf{Fld}$ is the full subcategory of $\textbf{CRing}$ where the objects are fields.

If you want to see what this actually looks like, you can consider $\bigsqcup_{\textbf{Fld}} F(k)/\sim$, where $\sim$ is the equivalence relation *generated* by the relation $x \sim y$ for $x \in F(k)$ and $y \in F(K)$ if there exists $L$ and $f: k \to L$ and $g: K \to L$ such that $F(f)(x) = F(g)(y)$. Now, if such an $L$ existed always, then this would be an equivalence relation, but if not, then you have to basically force transitivity. So I'm wondering to what extent you really are doing this.

Comment: Yes, the complex numbers themselves contain a copy of any $\mathbb{Q}_p$ since it is in fact the algebraic closure of all of them.

Comment: But the $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is not a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, or am I missing something?

Comment: No, it is clearly not a finite extension (it is of course trivially an extension).

Comment: More generally, the complex numbers contain an isomorphic copy of any field of characteristic zero and continuum cardinality.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, I'll edit the question accordingly. By the way @M10687, where can I find a reference for this fact? Also, is there something analogous to $\mathbb{C}$ with respect to this property in characteristic $p$?

Comment: The Wikipedia page for "characteristic zero" states it and references a book by enderton. I would post a link but I'm using a phone right now

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll look for it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that every field injects into every sufficiently large algebraically closed field of the same characteristic.

Comment: ... and, of course, two fields of different characteristic cannot have a common extension. Which may or may not answer your actual question.

Comment: Yeah I'm satisfied, because I start with the case that $F,K$ both contain a common subfield. Thanks!

Comment: Note that even restricting to a fixed characteristic, the category of fields is not filtered because there are typically many morphisms between two fields (which cannot be coequalized in any extension).